# Circular type dependency in c++ with container iterators (GCC fails, while MSVC ok)

Tags: c++, g++, unordered-map

Original code that I wrote worked fine out of the box with microsoft's compiler, but doesn't compile with gcc (4.7.4):
Here's simplified code:

```
// test.cpp
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

struct order_rec;
typedef unordered_map<int, order_rec> placed_orders_t;
typedef placed_orders_t::iterator placed_order_iterator;
typedef unordered_map<int, placed_order_iterator> book_list_t;
typedef book_list_t::iterator book_list_iterator;
struct order_rec
{
    int a;
    book_list_iterator bi;
};

int main()
{
    book_list_t test1;
    order_rec test2;
}
```

g++ doesn't like this line: `typedef placed_orders_t::iterator placed_order_iterator;`, it errors out because that by that line `struct order_rec` isn't fully declared.

As you can see I have a map `placed_orders_t` of int => order_rec, then I have another map `book_list_t` that maps int to iterators into `placed_orders_t` map. Then, the order_rec itself stores an interator into `book_list_t` map.

Note, that I believe that it's a bug in gcc's implementation of unordered_map (or perhaps compiler itself): if I typedef `placed_orders_t` as an std::map then everything compiles fine; however, I do need to use unordered maps there.

What could be used as a workaround?

Here's relevant part from g++ compilation

```
g++-4.7 -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=c++11 -c test.cpp
...
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/unordered_map.h:264:11:   required from ‘class std::unordered_map<int, order_rec>’
test.cpp:7:24:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:94:11: error: ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::second’ has incomplete type
test.cpp:5:8: error: forward declaration of ‘struct order_rec’
```

Comment: Why can't you define `order_rec` before typedefing `placed_orders_t`?

Comment: @cocarin it has a member `book_list_iterator bi;` which is iterator into `book_list_t`, where `book_list_t` is a map of itr => `placed_orders_t`, where `placed_orders_t` is a map of int => `order_rec`. In other words, order_rec cannot be defined before fully declaring `book_list_iterator`

Comment: Do you need a real `iterator`, or would a pointer suffice? I ask because this works: `typedef pair<const int, order_rec>* placed_order_pointer;`. But I guess you need an iterator

Comment: It would be helpful to your question to post the precise error message output generated from the gcc failed compile. Fwiw, it likewise pukes on compile with clang 3.8.

Comment: @WhozCraig added g++ error output

Comment: @AaronMcDaid the reason I have iterator there is because in my code when I need to manipulate data I need to remove values from maps. That's why I keep iterators there to avoid duplicated searches.

Comment: Thanks. clang is a bit more descriptive in its dump, but essentially the same. In a pinch I suppose you could just shelter your `bi` as a `std::unique_ptr` rather than as it is now.  Regardless, great care should be taken when stowing all those iterators, as a change in the underlying sequences could invalidate them quickly.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm fully aware about possible consequences of storing iterators. This code is fully wrapped and used internally, no problems with iterators (if you follow rules of iterator's invalidation in containers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a very nice solution, but we can change `order_rec` and declare it early.

```
struct  book_list_iterator;
struct order_rec
{   
    int a;
    vector    <book_list_iterator> bi;
};
```

This works because `vector` explicitly allows incomplete types as the member type.

(I did consider `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` instead of `vector`, but I think this is the easiest way to avoid having to write copy constructor for order_rec)

To access an individual iterator, we'll need `->bi.at(0)`, not just `->bi`.

Finally, `book_list_iterator` isn't a typedef, but a struct instead

```
typedef unordered_map<int, order_rec> placed_orders_t;
typedef placed_orders_t::iterator placed_order_iterator;
typedef unordered_map<int, placed_order_iterator> book_list_t;

struct  book_list_iterator : public book_list_t::iterator
{
};
```

Comment: interesting approach : ) I'll try. I think, effectively I can remove vector and simply use pointer to new'ed copy of `book_list_t::iterator` or `struct book_list_iterator` which migh aggregate the iterator instead of inheriting from it.

Comment: ..it all effectively boils down to `typedef unordered_map<int, order_rec*> placed_orders_t;` and I'd need to manually `new`/`delete` the order_recs

Comment: You could even use `typedef unordered_map<int, vector<order_rec>>`. I'm just using `vector` as a lazy way to avoid raw pointers and having to `new`/`delete`/`make_shared`/`make_unique`. It does mean, of course, that we need to ensure the `vector` always has exactly one element.

Comment: I ended up using most obvious simple workaround: `typedef unordered_map<int, unique_ptr<order_rec> > placed_orders_t;` I `new` it once only when inserting records (I had special code for first time insertion anyways), so, it kind of works around unnecessary limitations that come from unordered_map's impl from g++

Comment: Worth noting that this works because `vector` explicitly allows for incomplete types.

Answer (score 3):

The code you have is undefined behavior. When you write:

```
struct order_rec;
typedef unordered_map<int, order_rec> placed_orders_t;
typedef placed_orders_t::iterator placed_order_iterator;
```

This requires instantiation of `placed_orders_t`, which requires instantiation of `unordered_map<int, order_rec>`. `order_rec` is incomplete at this point. From [res.on.functions]:

> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases: [...] if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component, unless specifically allowed for that component.

Some class templates in the standard library allow for incomplete types (like `unique_ptr` or `vector`), but `unordered_map` isn't one of them, so the effects of that are undefined. Failing to compile is a permissible effect. Note that the same is true of `map`, even if your code compiles.

You'll have to have `placed_orders_t::mapped_type` be a type that can be used in this context. Perhaps `std::unique_ptr<order_rec>`?

Comment: Maybe not undefined but unspecified?

Comment: @EdgarRokyan No, undefined.

Comment: Yes, seems to be the case. Some code in `unordered_map` seems to use pair<first, second>::second_type somewhere, which means that order_rec has to be fully specified. I'd say it's a bug in libstdc++ in g++, unnecessary code perhaps triggers that unnecessary prohibition.

Comment: @Pavel It's not a bug in libstdc++ or gcc or clang.

Comment: @Barry I'd need to see and dig into their stl code to see where and why it happens, perhaps some leftovers there that trigger this limitation. This is a bug in a sense that it bugs me, not that it violates the spec ;)

Comment: @Barry For example. `map<K, V>/unordered_map<K, V>` stores internally data as `typedef pair<K, V> value_type`. If you try to write anywhere in implementation of map/unordered_map something like `value_type::second_type` instead of simply `V`, then you'll get that same 'bug' that bugs me, while you'll still be ok according to the specs.

Comment: @Pavel Again, it's not a bug, it's not a 'bug'. The standard states that it's undefined behavior. If you're relying on a specific implementation of undefined behavior, you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a compiler issue. But generally it should not work, because when you use `typedef unordered_map<int, order_rec> placed_orders_t;` it requires size of `order_rec` to be known, so that it can allocate memory accordingly, which in your case is not known, so either use `order_rec*` in place of `order_rec` or move the definition of `struct order_rec` to before you use it.

Comment: I don't think it's the case here. Also note, that std::map works just fine. Internally, IMO everything is used as a pointer to `order_rec`. You only need to have `order_rec` fully defined when you instantiate `placed_orders_t`

Comment: The typedef doesn't allocate anything, and therefore the size isn't necessary at that point. The following line, looking up the `::iterator` appears to be the problem

Comment: You are right about that, but in your case you are also using it's iterator, which can only be declared for known types.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid that's what I specified that `::iterator` triggers an error, which shouldn't happen IMO

Comment: @VikashKesarwani I'm pretty sure that class' typedef  will work in case of pointer to some forward declared struct. Internally, unordered_map impl should use pointers to `order_rec` anyways. Also, please *note* it works with std::map, pointless to argue that it's invalid for some reason (and I think it's valid to do the way I did it).

Comment: @Pavel if you look at the declarations `std::map::iterator` is of a `_Rb_Type` while `std::unordered_map::iterator` is of `_Hashtable` type, which in turn uses `std::pair<_TKey, _TValue>` and it does not use pointers.

Comment: @VikashKesarwani perhaps you are right, my code depended on how unordered_map is implemented internally in dinkumware stdlib (ms compiler uses it). Still, hashtable should perhaps use pointers/lists to `pair<key, value>`, e.g. it shouldn't need fully specified order_rec for typedefs